# Get the rows with max values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Doing a function for taking row with max value in Pandas Dataframe, looking like this:

```
def max_row(df, col):

    max_index = df[col].idxmax()

    return df.loc[[max_index]]
```

So it works like this: `max_row(test_df, 'Col_A')`

What I try to do is to show like that 2 rows of Dataframe. Currently using `nlargest()` function but it seems that smth wrong on `loc` side:

```
def max_rows(df, col, n):

    max_indexes = df[col].nlargest(n)
    max_indexes = list(max_indexes.index)

    return df.loc[[max_indexes]]
```

How can this be written to fulfil the task?

Thanks!

Comment: Change to `return df.loc[max_indexes]`

Comment: Can you please write it as an answer I ll accept it if you don't mind

Comment: OK :-) Will do ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
def max_rows(df, col, n):

    max_indexes = df[col].nlargest(n)
    max_indexes = list(max_indexes.index)

    return df.loc[max_indexes]
```